# Return a string based on matching simple condition in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to have a cell that automatically summarises information like in the Summary row in the example below:

| Vegan | Lactose Intolerant | Gluten Free | **Summary ** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y | n | y | Vegan, Gluten Free |
| n | y | n | Lactose Intolerant |

If I use an IF function I could do the one column, e.g. =(IF(B3 = "y", "Lactose Intolerant")

But I don't know if you can combine multiple functions together, e.g. =(IF(A3 = "y", "Vegan") AND IF(B3 = "y", "Lactose Intolerant") AND (IF(C3 = "y", "Gluten Free")

What I'd like is if Excel can scan through all the rows, and add together some text based on whether there is a "y" in the row.

I know the above function doesn't work, but I'm trying to illustrate what I'm hoping to achieve. Is it possible?

Thanks